# Remove Minutes from a Timespan duration

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, timespan, duration

I know this has been asked before but i couldn't figure out how to get the answers given working for my particular example. This is a WPF application written in C# and i'm trying to remove a number of minutes from a timespan.

So far i've got the application to figure out the duration by removing a Start Time from a Finish Time, but what i'm trying to do now is remove the number of minutes the user has entered into the form.

Here's the code so far

```
 private void testcal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string startTime = teststart.Text;
        string finishTime = testfinish.Text;

        // Trying to deduct this lunchTime var from the duration TimeSpan
        string lunchTime = testlunch.Text;

        TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Parse(finishTime).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(startTime));
        testlabel.Text = duration.ToString(@"hh\:mm");

    }
```

**Edit - Updated to include private void**

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "remove a number of minutes"? Subtract? Round? It would really help if you'd show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem - with input and expected output. (Perhaps `AddMinutes` with a negative value is all you're looking for?)

Comment: I'm trying to knock off the number of minutes stored in `lunchTime` from the `TimeSpan duration`, the `lunchTime` data comes from a textbox on the form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With user input it would be.

```
string startTime = teststart.Text;
string finishTime = testfinish.Text;
string lunchTime = testlunch.Text;

TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Parse(finishTime).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(startTime)).
    Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Int32.Parse(lunchtime)));
```

Comment: You goddamned beautiful man, this worked perfectly thanks so much :) Here's the working code;

`TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Parse(finishTime).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(startTime)).Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Int32.Parse(lunchTime)));
            testlabel.Text = duration.ToString(@"hh\:mm");`

Answer (score 9):

Are you asking how to subtract minutes from a TimeSpan?

If so try something like

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan().Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
```

Comment: I'm trying to return the original length of time between the `startTime` and `finishTime` and then remove the number of minutes specified by the user, stored in `lunchTime`

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.Parse("10/09/2021");
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

TimeSpan subtract = now - selectedDate;
subtract -= new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0);
```